# Add an error message on questions merge into Transifex

Tags: bug, status-declined, moderator-tools, localization, international-sites

If you are trying to merge questions, there could be an error:

> At least one of the questions for the merge must be closed

There is no such string in Transifex, so we can't translate it. Could you add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transifex work isn't something the team is currently focused on so I've updated the status to declined.

Comment: If you want to keep the international sites (SO.es, SO.jp, SO.pt, SO.ru) then you should be focused on Traducir and Transifex (i.e., making sure the source strings are complete and up to date), because without those you don't have an international site.

Comment: Does is mean that international sites are not in your focus right now in general?